# Scraping text from a page with jsoup

Tags: android, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to scrap some text from a webpage using Jsoup in android. I used these code:

```
  package com.example.scrappping1;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;


  import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
  import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
  import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
  import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    String URL = "http://www.bengalinux.org/cgi-bin/abhidhan/index.pl?en_word=like";

    Document site = null;

    try 
    {
     site = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/523.10.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10").get();
    } 
     catch (IOException e)
      {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fdf",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

     Elements newsline = site.select("div.dict_entry");
     String output = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < newsline.size(); i++) {

         output = newsline.get(i).text();
       }           

      text.setText(output);                                
}// onCreate
    }// end
```

But I am getting this error

> "The application has stopped unexpectedly"

I dont understand why? How can i solve this?

Comment: Post your full stack trace. Is it a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Just inside <manifest> </manifest> of the AndroidManifest.xml file.